# In member function, is it possible to interpret a parameter "parent" as a child temporarilly?

Tags: c++

```
bool  COLL::Rectangle::collides (const Collider & other) const noexcept
{
    bool boolean;
    switch (other.type)
    {
        case RECTANGLE: // i have defined a enum type to do introspection
             //i am sure that what will reach this part will be a Rectangle, which inherits from Collider.

            boolean = (contains (other.origin) || contains (other.origin.first));
            break;
        case CIRCLE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return boolean;
}
```

My question is : can i say to my compiller : "hey, for these few lines, the object will be seen as a Rectangle." Maybe dynamic or static cast ? I didn't get it too well.

if a *Rectangle* is casted as a *Rectangle*, will there be issue ?

thank you very much.

Comment: Following @Bathsheba's (good) advice will probably lead you to the Visitor pattern (so you know what to google).

Comment: Why not define `contains`, or better still, `collides` as a virtual method, and implement it for all types? Problem solved and no type field necessary! And better design.

Comment: Because I will need to give it as a generic Collider therefore I believe (if i don't speak nonsense) I need this profile of function

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume this makes perfect sense, and is the motivation for the Visitor pattern. Also, it seems I'm travelling through time.

Comment: thank you guys ! (yeah, save the 2 pins.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that `other` is a `Rectangle` at that point in the code, then you can safely `static_cast` it.

```
case RECTANGLE:
    Rectangle& rect = static_cast<Rectangle&>(other);
    //...
    break;
```

Another solution which might be a bit cleaner would be to use double-dispatch via the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). For instance, you could define `collide(Rectangle&)` and `collide(Circle&)` functions, then do the double-dispatch like `other.collide(*this);`. Doing so would eliminate the need for a type enum.